# Assigning a reducer for a dynamic store property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a reducer for a property in my state tree that gets created from user events.

My state tree looks like this:

```
{
  session: { session object },
  dashboard: {
    id: 'id001',
    charts: {
      'cid001': { dimensions: { ... }, more objects... },
      'cid002': { dimensions: { ... }, more objects... }
    }

  } 
}
```

New `charts` properties come in through Redux when a user clicks the Add Chart button. The key is set to the chart id, `cid`.

I'm currently using `combineReducers()` to set up the reducer tree.

```
import session from './session';
import charts from './charts';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  session,
  dashboard: combineReducers({
    charts
  });
});
```

I am able to nest reducers like this if I know the property names ahead of time. However, I'd like to avoid having a massive reducer for the `charts` property, since each chart inside it could have up to 20 more objects on it that need reducing, `dimensions` is just one example.

Is there a way to set a reducer for the `charts['cidxxx'].dimensions`, and other sub-properties? Are there wildcard tokens for this? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Object spreads would be nice for something like this.

```
function chartsReducer(state, {payload}) {
  const {cid} = payload;
  const currentChart = state[cid] || {};
  return {...state, [cid]: {...currentChart, ...payload}};
}
```

If you are looking to go deeper than that in terms of property trees, it may be worth thinking about how to change the shape of your data to match how you are using it.